# How to set drush alias for remote site behind jump server?

Tags: 8, drush

Drupal 8 site (8.5.3) with drush 8 (8.1.16) both equal on local and remote. Connection to remote is through jump server - log in to jump (ssh -L 2004:remote.com:22 -l username jump.server.com), in other terminal connect to the remote (ssh -l username -p 2004 localhost). All this work fine. I keep these connected, and test drush in third terminal.

Aliases are at drush/aliases.drushrc.php in project dir.

```
$aliases['site.r'] = [
  'root' => '/home/username/drupal8/web',
  'uri' => 'http://remote.site.com',
  'remote-host' => 'localhost',
  'remote-user' => 'username',
  'ssh-options' => '-p 2004'
];
```

drush @site.r status -v show me that the aliases are found but result is from local installation.

edit:

```
sve@eb850 .../panel-d8.local/web (master>) $ drush @kp.r status -v
Loaded alias @kp.r from file                                            [notice]
/var/www/vhosts/panel-d8.local/web/../drush/aliases.drushrc.php
Loading outputformat engine.                                            [notice]
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                                         
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini                             
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                                                
 Drush script           :  /var/www/vhosts/panel-d8.local/vendor/drush/drush/dr 
                           ush.php                                              
 Drush version          :  8.1.16                                               
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                                 
 Drush configuration    :                                                       
 Drush alias files      :                                                       

Command dispatch complete                                               [notice]
```

edit 2: This is a sub-site of multi-site, drush aliases works on local and remote by self in right way.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you maybe add the result? No screenshots please.

Comment: added the drush @site.r result (with real names)

Comment: Did you try clearing Drush cache? And you should devo upgrade Drush to v9!

Comment: it is not suitable at this time to do this kind of changes as this is a part of multi-site and many others will be affected